# Spa tub frame too high

Tags: bathtub

So the framer built the oval spa tub frame about an 1 1/2" to perhaps 2" (don't recall exact right now) too high. I told the plumber just to raise the floor where the legs will sit with solid lumber (2x4, 2x6, perhaps from a rafter beam that's about 1 1/2" thick nailed with additional plywood to make up the remaining height if needed). The plumber insisted just spraying high density insulation foam on the floor and resting the legs on the foam once it hardens. I'm afraid that the insulation spray foam will crumble to particles over time and the spa will be left being supported from the lip/ledger. Any pointers?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have a couple of unregistered user accounts. Please [register](/help/why-register) one of them then [merge them](/help/merging-accounts) together, which will allow you to [edit](/help/privileges/create-posts), and [comment on](/help/privileges/comment) any of your posts and [accept an answer](/help/someone-answers) on your question. Thanks, and welcome to the site!

Answer (score 2):

I would definitely NOT try to support the full weight of a tub with any kind of insulation.

I would not even use lumber since it can swell or warp.

I think I would find patio blocks or bricks the right thickness or pour concrete or mortar leg supports.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how the tub is constructed, I always placed tarpaper, wire lath fastened with roofing nails and masonry cement under the tub. Place enough masonry cement under where the tub will set and "float it down just so the edge touches the support framing. The edge of the tub is NOT supposed to support the weight of the tub.